# Vue3 webcomponents production build problem

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-cli, vite

I'm trying to migrate my vue2 webcomponent to vue3, although the problem comes when i'm creating a build for production.

I was using the vue-cli with `--target wc` which now displays an error stating that vue3 webcomponent support is still under development.

Removing the `--target` option my build files are way different, i was relying on the .min files that without this option are not builded.

What alternative I have? Does vite provide the same build outputs that previously vue-cli gave with vue2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now -may 2022- the vue-cli-service does not support at all [--target wc](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/ce97e62304e884c4277aaa1b605f735253e4205b/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/resolveWcConfig.js#L18)
In fact in the source code it is completely disabled

```js
if (vueMajor === 3) {
    abort(`Vue 3 support of the web component target is still under development.`)
  }
```